# StackMob Android

Tags: android, iphone, database, stackmob

Can I make database tables (like tables for sqlite in local db) on StackMob via android App?

How can I insert and get data to and from tables on StackMob account via android App?

And Kindly also tell me what's the maximum data we can store on StackMob?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find everything you need on the [StackMob developer website](http://developer.stackmob.com).

There's many [tutorials](http://developer.stackmob.com/tutorials) on, for example, how to [save an object](http://developer.stackmob.com/tutorials/android/Save-an-Object) or [read it](http://developer.stackmob.com/tutorials/android/Read-an-Object).

This will be a good start.

Comment: can we save images on stackmob as well, and whats is the permission for maximum net size of data on stackmob single account

Comment: Agreed the developer website and tutorials are the best place to start. Text data is stored as objects and binary data is stored via Amazon S3.  Once the binary data is saved to S3, the URL to the file is saved along with the object in the designated field.  [How to upload to S3](http://developer.stackmob.com/tutorials/android/Upload-to-S3) and [how to configure your schema for binary data](http://developer.stackmob.com/tutorials/dashboard/Adding-a-Binary-Field-to-Schemas)